# Make jquery tabs more responsive

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've implemented jQueury UI tabs.

If you move over them too quickly, the tab where the mouse is currently on, doesn't activate.

I've done a jsFiddle below which sort of demonstrates this.
The problem is more emphatic on the site because of the amount of Javascript running concurrently. Is there a way to make the current tab activate based on different events without customizing the jQuery-UI code?

It is CDN and part of a larger framework.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ariestattoo/pQqbr/5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your duration from a string ('fast') to an integer representing the delay you want. The integer value represents the number of milliseconds the transition should take.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pQqbr/10/)**

```
$(".tabs").tabs({
    event: "mouseover",
    fx: {
        opacity: 'toggle',
        duration: 1
    }
});
```

From the docs:

> The duration option can be a string representing one of the three
>   predefined speeds ("slow", "normal", "fast") or the duration in
>   milliseconds to run an animation (default is "normal").

Comment: I suspect marketing will be unhappy that they have lost there smoothly fading transition...

Comment: It doesn't have to be lost, you can change the integer to something between fast and zero. I believe fast = 200ms.